# AsParallel writing to same object

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a Dictionary with Key-Value pair where Value is a complex Object.
Becaouse of a speed I have used AsParalle(). 
Problem that occures is that in some of my return objects are placed multiple results of other Key-Value pair.

For examle:
ResutDict has multiple Key-Value pairs.

```
public IDictionary<string, IOutboundResult> ResultDict
{
  get { return m_ResultDict; }
  set { m_ResultDict = value; }
}

ResultDict.AsParallel()
          .WithDegreeOfParallelism(amountOfThreads)
          .ForAll(kvp => { DO YOUR THING AND RETURN OBJECT S_Out}
```

All of them should return one Object. That later will be serialized into XML.

```
public class S_Out : ISerializable
{
    private List<details> detailField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("details")]
    public List<details> details
    {
        get { return detailField; }
        set { detailField = value; }
    } 
}

public class details
{
        private string idField;       
        private string countryField;
        private string town_cityField;
        private string postcodeField;
        private List<extract> extractField;

    public string id
    {
        get { return idField; }
        set { idField = value; }
    }

    public string country
    {
        get { return countryField; }
        set { countryField = value; }
    }

    public string town_city
    {
        get { return town_cityField; }
        set { town_cityField = value; }
    }

    public string postcode
    {
        get { return postcodeField; }
        set { postcodeField = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement("extract")]
    public List<extract> extract
    {
        get { return extractField; }
        set { extractField = value; }
    }
}
```

This list of details is there only for some other cases, but in this particular case should contain only one detail. 
During Parallel different Threads write in there so in some files I have no detail object, and in some of them whole list of details.
[image]
[image]
It should be one detail for one xml file.
Have anyone Idea why is this happening?

Comment: It is not clear what is happening in your code.  Where and how do you write?  If you add multiple items from different threads, you should use `ConcurrentDictionary` instread.

Comment: Same it s hard to understand your question. Are your data thread safe? It not do use lock ?

Comment: I have edited my question for clarification. Program is very complex, so I tried to do my best to simplify it. I cannot lock everything while than I lose the reason to use Threads. In sequential mode everything works just fine, but it needs to be more quick

Comment: Please post a [MCVE], it's basically impossible for anyone here to tell you what went wrong in a piece of code *you did not post*. You may also be interested to learn about auto-properties, they would save you a lot of typing.

Comment: @nvoigt thanks for goodhearted advice. Within the program that is so big and compex it is nearly imposible to do so. And also it is something that is in development for so many years and develoed by many developers. I am merly trying to improve the system, because the demand and data load is geting bigger.
Properties were autocrated from xsd, so we did minimal typing :-)